# Unicode Spreadsheet to MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get a document from Excel or OpenOffice that contains UTF 16 characters into MySQL, but I can't find the best way to export the document so that phpmyadmin will read it. I can export out of NeoOffice as "unicode" format, but the closest option in MySQL is ucs2. When I try that format, it just spins and thinks. UTF8 doesn't support all the characters that I am needing.

Comment: Can't use `LOAD DATA INFILE` cuz of the UTF16 issue: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF8 does support all the characters of UTF16, it's just that UTF16 crams everything into 2 bytes, while UTF8 can take up to 4 bytes.

MySQL doesn't support UTF16 at this time, because the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/endianness) of the encoding isn't specified, so correctness can't be guaranteed at any time. UTF16 was [supposed to be supported for Mysql 6](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32393), but since 6 was put on ice, I have no idea what has happened with it.

**SQLite supports UTF16 by default though.**

Answer (score 0):

Save as UTF-8. If you can't save as UTF-8 directly from your Office software (oh dear!) then load into Notepad-or-similar and save out as UTF-8.

As UTFs, both UTF-8 and UTF-16 can represent the same, complete range of all Unicode characters. UTF-8 is a sensible encoding for files on disc; UTF-16LE (or “Unicode” as Windows very misleadingly describes it) isn't really. UTF-16 can be useful for in-memory storage, but MySQL doesn't use it. Stick with UTF-8 for MySQL storage.